# Facebook Graph API permissions for public pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Please tell me if I didn't miss any required permissions and didn't take something superfluous for my app in Facebook Graph Api.

My goal is to:
Access any public [profiles'/pages'/groups'] [posts/stories/feed] on [facebook/instagram]

The permissions I'm going to choose:

- pages_show_list
- instagram_basic
- user_posts
- pages_read_engagement [needed for instagram_basic]
- Groups API
- Page Public Content Access

Is everything right? Thanks

Comment: On the documentation for what you're trying to do typically tells you what permissions you'd need to do them, check out the Facebook graph api docs

Comment: @UriahsVictor Thanks for your reply! I did it, just wanted to make sure that I'm not missings something. And at least I fount out, that "Read media objects, such as stories" permissions are included into instagram_manage_comments. It was surprising enough for me to ask for consulting on this topic :)